# How to override sylius 0.18 in composer with my own VCS repository?

Tags: git, github, composer-php, sylius

I must to keep 0.18 of sylius/sylius

i had fork the master and create a new branch 0.18, merge inside some PR.

Now i want to use this repository instead sylius/sylius v0.18 tag

here my composer.json

```
{
"name":        "sylius/sylius-standard",
"description": "Starting point for projects powered by Sylius eCommerce.",
"keywords":    ["symfony", "symfony2", "sylius", "distribution", "ecommerce", "cart", "shopping"],
"type":        "project",
"license":     "MIT",
"homepage":    "http://sylius.org",
"authors": [
    {
        "name":     "Paweł Jędrzejewski",
        "homepage": "http://pjedrzejewski.com"
    },
    {
        "name":     "Sylius project",
        "homepage": "http://sylius.org"
    },
    {
        "name":     "Community contributions",
        "homepage": "http://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/contributors"
    }
],
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/ibasaw/DoctrineBehaviors"
    },
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/ibasaw/sylius"
    }
],
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6",

    "sylius/sylius": "^0.18@dev",
    ......
},
"require-dev": {
    "behat/behat": "^3.0",
    "behat/symfony2-extension": "^2.0",
    "behat/mink-extension": "^2.0",
    "behat/mink-browserkit-driver": "^1.2",
    "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "^1.2",
    "behat/mink":  "^1.6",
    "coduo/php-matcher": "^2.1@dev",
    "phpspec/phpspec": "^2.4",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^4.1",
    "lakion/api-test-case": "^1.0@dev"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Symfony\\Cmf\\Bundle\\CreateBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::downloadCreateAndCkeditor",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Symfony\\Cmf\\Bundle\\CreateBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::downloadCreateAndCkeditor",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "": "src/",
        "Context": "features/"
    }
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"extra": {
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "0.18"
    },
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    }
}
```

}

when i do a composer update, in the vendor directory it takes sylius/sylius and not ibasaw/sylius

Why ?

How to force to use the VCS with my new branch 0.18 ?

Comment: i had replaced  "branch-alias": { "dev-master": "0.18" } by  "branch-alias": { "dev-master": "0.18-dev" } It seem to take the good repository. But now i got this problem: Fatal error: Class 'Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Kernel\Kernel' not found in /var/www/sources/xxx/app/AppKernel.php on line 9

Comment: Mostly, because `Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Kernel\Kernel` was replaced by   `Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Application\Kernel` between v0.18 and v0.19. You can check it [here](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/v0.19.0/app/AppKernel.php#L12)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. give your fork an own package name (name field in composer.json)
2. use https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#replace replace to declare your package replacing the original package
3. require *your* package in your root composer.json

Answer (score 0):

Add your forked Sylius repository like this in your composer.json

```
"repositories": [
{
  "type": "git",
  "url": "https://github.com/ylastapis/Sylius.git"
}],
```

You can either require your master branch or create a custom branch (to merge your code pending that Sylius team accepts your merge, mine is called master-poc)

In the require section, require YOUR branch, prefixed by "dev-". so master became dev-master, thus my branch master-poc is now dev-master-poc

```
"require": {
    "sylius/sylius": "dev-master-poc"
  },
```

I also got a branch alias, Can't remember if it's still usefull

```
  "extra": {
    "branch-alias": {
      "dev-master": "1.0-dev"
    }
  }
```

Some link to the doc: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository

Comment: it override, but got the error Fatal error: Class 'Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Kernel\Kernel' not found in /var/www/sources/xxx/app/AppKernel.php on line 9